# Обрезать таймзону и милесекунды

Tags: python, datetime

Есть дата:

```
 d =  datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

Как получить обрезать дату до секунд

```
2020-04-25 03:11:48
```

Можно обрезать так, но так получится строка и придется еще раз преобразовывать дату

```
datetime.datetime.strftime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Можно как то в одну операцию это сделать

Comment: А чем вас строка не устраивает? Если речь не о строке, тогда в чём смысл этой обрезки?

Comment: Если надо обнулить значения, то есть `d.replace(microsecond=0, tzinfo=None)`

Comment: @telate22 То, что вы написали в постановке задачи: "d =   2020-04-25 03:11:48.445626+00:00" недопустимо в языке Python. Уточните, что на самом деле означает эта запись.

Comment: Вариант с обнулением подойдет. Спасибо!